# Changing visiblity screwing up events in C#?

Tags: c#, winforms

I have setup a Panel that has a number of Buttons on it. These Buttons Visible Property is set to false. When I move the mouse over the Panel they became Visible and when I move the mouse out of the Panel they once again became invisible. This all works fine.

The code to do this is:

```
private void _Display_MouseEnter(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        foreach (Control C in _Display.Controls)
        {
            C.Visible = true;
        }
    }

    private void _Display_MouseLeave(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        foreach (Control C in _Display.Controls)
        {
            C.Visible = false;
        }
    }
```

The problem is the Events I have set for the Buttons seem to get removed by doing this. If I don't change the Buttons visiblity the events fire as normal. I have set the events in the Designer.

Am I missing something or is this how its supposed to work and I have to resubscribe my events each time I change the Buttons visiblity?

Thanks
Danny

Comment: Changing the visibility of a button surely doesn't remove the event handler, the problem must be somewhere else.

Answer (score 0):

I did some research on that and apparently when the cursor enters one of the buttons the Panel's MouseEnter and MouseLeave events fire until the cursor leaves that button so what it does is not allowing your buttons to catch the Click event.

I think the best solution would be to get the cursor position and check if it is within your panel and then set your buttons visibility.

Comment: I was concerned that the Panel may be holding onto the Cursor as moving the Cursor over the Buttons didn't make the Panel disappear again which I though would fire the Panels MouseLeave event. I try some stuff and get back to you.

Comment: Have check a few things and moving the Cursor over the Button does make it disappear again as the Mouse does leave the Panel, the Panel just isn't being redrawn but of course the Button is not visible to the system. This is a whole different issue.